# Traveling between Canada and China using two passports

Tags: international-travel, dual-nationality

I traveled back to China using my Chinese passport for summer break, when I’m travelling back to Canada, I’m using my Chinese passport booking a flight to Seattle (I have a Visa) that is stopping in Canada, would I be able to enter Canada using my Canadian passport even if China doesn’t allow dual citizenship?

Comment: How are you still a Chinese citizen if I may ask? Any lack of visas observed by the Chinese and it's supposed to be gone!

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you, you must.  To enter Canada on a Chinese passport, you'll need an eTA - an electronic travel authorization - and these are not available to Canadian citizens, even if they hold a foreign citizenship as well.

China may not recognize your dual citizenship, but Canada certainly recognizes your Canadian citizenship.

Comment: "To enter Canada on a Chinese passport, you'll need an eTA - an electronic travel authorization" The Chinese passport cannot get eTA (unless they are a US permanent resident) -- they would have to get a visitor visa to visit Canada. However, with the Chinese passport they can [transit Canada without a visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/china-transit-eligibility.html) to/from the US under certain conditions, and an eTA is not needed.